A question about complex algebraic numbers as roots of polynomials.
Suppose I have the root of a polynomial that has integer  coefficients, i.e., it is a complex algebraic number. Can it ever be of the form $x =  \alpha + \tfrac{p}{q}i$ where $\alpha$ is the irrational real part and the imaginary part is rational?
I know that they can both be rational; the real part can be rational and the imaginary part irrational; they can both be irrational; but I'm not sure about the real part being irrational, and the imaginary part rational.

"real" coefficients does not tell us that the root is algebraic.  $x-\pi$ has real coefficients.

And I don't understand your question. Are you asking if a complex algebraic number can have irrational real part and rational imaginary part?  Sure.  Like $\sqrt 2$  or, if you prefer $\sqrt 2 +i$.  Or are you asking something entirely different?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. If you edit your question to clarify it as @lulu suggested, could you explain why the theorem you mentioned would be relevant? It's about exponentiation.

Sorry, Lulu I meant integer coefficients. I corrected it.

note that the algebraic numbers form a ring and $i$ is in there so if $\alpha=a+ib$ algebraic then $i\alpha=-b+ia$ and then $-i\alpha, i\bar \alpha$ are also algebraic so if a property holds for the combination (real, imaginary) it will also hold for the combination (imaginary, real)

@Conrad, that is true. When you put it that way, it's pretty easy to see. ;) Thanks!

@Conrad, this may be fairly trivial or even wrong but, I find it interesting that it seems to me that 1 -√2  may be a solution to a second degree equation, but (1 -√2) may not be algebraic for a second degree equation.

If $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic of degrees $m,n$ then $\alpha \beta$ has degree at most $mn$ (and divisible by both $m,n$) so here the degree of $i+\sqrt 2$ is $2$ or $4$ and looking at (galois) conjugates it indeed is $4$ (as there are $4$ such $\pm \sqrt 2 \pm i$ while for $1-\sqrt 2 i$ there is only one galois conjugate (the complex conjugate) so indeed its degree is $2$

HINT: $e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{i}{2}$ is a root of $x^{12}-1$. This is a classic example.

Thanks, Mike. I'm struggling a bit, as a novice, at the notion of a complex algebraic irrational number  of degree d, in the context of Liouville's Theorem. In this case, I'm assuming that if  =  + , that either a or b, or both have to be irrational. I'm also assuming that if a = 0, that we essentially are back to the real part only proof.
